# Do I need to remove my shower to patch the subfloor?

Tags: bathroom, shower, subfloor

The flooring near the corner of my shower was soft and rotted out. I thought I could just cut it out and replace that section of subfloor but after pulling some out, it appears the subfloor runs 3 inches under the shower. Do I need to remove this shower in order to replace the subflooring?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can add some 2x6 ( assuming your floor assembly is 2x8 ) perpendicular to your joists to pickup the localized floor loading in this area.

You can either use hangers, toe nail to the recessed joist (hard) or you can end nail to another piece of 2x6 and then face nail that to the recessed joist.  You'll probably need to cut a little more flooring to get to the next joist but that is in the opposite direction of the shower.